# How does the "complex" macro modify the "double" and "float" types in C?

Tags: c

What preprocessor/compiler magic happens in order to make the declaration:

```
#include <complex.h>
double complex foo;
```

resolve to a declaration of a complex double `foo`?

More specifically, how can I mimic this functionality to create, say, a `rabbit` type so that I could `#include "rabbit.h"` and then when I declare:

```
 double rabbit bar;
```

`bar` is declared as a type of my choosing?

Comment: `complex` isn't a keyword; it's simply a macro expanding to the keyword `_Complex`.

Comment: Edited to reflect the truth. Thanks @KerrekSB!

Comment: Why do you want to implement this instead of something like `typdef <whatever you want> rabbit` and then `rabbit bar`

Comment: @KerrekSB I realize that this is almost an answer to my question. Because `complex` expands to `_Complex` and `_Complex` is a [keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html/) in C99, the compiler must do the work of associating the label `foo` to the appropriate type, and I can't easily declare my own keywords. It would have been nice though!

Comment: @mstbaum I am implementing a type that functions very similarly to a `double` (alternate precision/additive properties), and felt that it modified a `double` in an analogous fashion to the how `_Complex` types modify a `double`. I realize that I should probably just give up and use a type named `double_rabbit`

Comment: @peterpants: No, if random developers could go around adding their own new keywords, that would be the exact opposite of "nice" :-S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with C99, `_Complex` is a keyword, part of the core language. Syntactically it's a *type specifier*, like `long` or `unsigned`. It can be used along with any of `float`, `double`, or `long double`.

Thus `_Complex double` is a type, built into the language.

The standard header `<complex.h>` defines `complex` as a macro that expands to `_Complex`. This is just for convenience. The keyword was given the spelling `_Complex` to avoid conflicting with valid pre-C99 code; the macro can be used to enable the more common term `complex` for complex types.

(The C11 standard makes complex types optional.)

There is no language mechanism for defining your own type specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You can't make `double rabbit x;` do something different, the same way you can't make `unsigned rabbit x;` do that.

`_Complex` is special cased in the language. There are three complex types: `float _Complex`, `double _Complex`, `long double _Complex`. As you can see, the `float/double/long double` is the modifier, just like `unsigned` or `long` or `short` are for `int`.

Comment: So why can `complex` do so? This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It answers the part when OP asks how he can create his types.

Comment: Syntactically, `_Complex`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `int` et al are all type specifiers. There's no real distinction between modifiers and non-modifiers, and the type specifiers can appear in any order. For example, `double _Complex long` is valid and equivalent to `long double _Complex`.